# Click a href to change a variable in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have generated a "Talks" scaffold for a yearly conference. Each talk consists of a name, title and the year it occurred.

I want to display only the talks from one specific year at a time.

In the app/views/talks/index.html.erb file I can do this with:

```
<% @year = 1978 %>
<% @talks.where(:year => @year).each do |talk| %>
```

Which will then list only talks from 1978.

I am also listing the years in which talks occurred in the sidebar (same file) using:

```
<ul>
<% Talk.uniq.pluck(:year).each do |year| %>
<li><a href="" ><%= year %></a></li>
</ul>
```

Which gives a list of years like:

- 1978
- 1979
- 1980
- ...And so on.

I want the user to be able click on a year to show only talks from that year.

Is there a way to set the @talks variable via the url?

Something like:

```
<li><a href="/talks?year=1978" ><%= year %></a></li>
```

Or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller:

```
def index
    @year = params[:year].to_i
    @year = 1978 if year < 1978
    @talks = Talk.where(:year => @year).to_a
end
```

Remove `<% @year = 1978 %>` in your view.

Replace `<% @talks.where(:year => @year).each do |talk| %>` by `<% @talks.each do |talk| %>`

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly as far as I can see. Nice and simple too!